# How to find similarity between two nodes in graph (NetworkX/ Python)

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, similarity

I've checked previous SO questions on NetworkX and most are about Graph-Graph similarity, but not Node-Node similarity. 
I wish to assess the similarity of two nodes in a graph, and I can't convert to vector space of attributes and do it that way because some attributes have no intrinsic order. An example should make it clear:

[image: Donut Graph]

Here it is clear to the human observer that ChocolateDonut is more similar to RingDonut than to PoundCake, but how does one extract that information from a graph? I roughly could guess at how one could do it in a brute force manner by comparing the in and out arcs for every node against every other node, but what would be the 'right' way to do this?

Also I need to be able to set constraints (for example, "Get object in graph most similar to ChocolateDonut that DOES NOT have sprinkles", etc.). So if the method searches only within constraints that's a bonus so that I don't have to filter the results afterwards.

The library used doesn't have to be NetworkX, anything that works in Python is fine.

Comment: That's a quite wide question. First thing you need to think of about defining a function for "similar". So you need to define a measure for similarity, which could be as you mentioned number of shared id's of the in and out nodes. After doing that I would first start with a brute force try. Just for proof of conzept. (Since the brute force is written quite fast)

Comment: Take a look at the approach Pandora uses to find similar songs.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_Genome_Project

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I feel that turning attributes into vectors won't work. For Pandora they had limited layers in their Phylogeny but I am aiming to expand to multiple recursive depths of attributes with their own attributes etc.- hence the use of a graph. I feel that creating a subgraph of a component and its attributes then comparing that subgraph against the subgraph of another component and its attributes is the right way to go, but not sure how to do this in networkx.

Answer (score 0):

Currently getting subgraph by getting all successors recursively like so:

```
def get_all_successors(G, node):
    succs = {node}; nxt={node}
    #Get all successors recursively
    while len(nxt)>0:
        nxt = nxt.union(set(G.successors(nxt.pop())))
        succs = succs.union(nxt)

    return succs

def get_subgraph(G, node):
    return nx.subgraph(G,get_all_successors(G, node))
```

Since in my network attributes are hierarchically lower than objects, this gives me each object's subgraph, then I can compare it to another object using laplacian spectrum.

Would love to hear feedback on this approach, as it seems ad-hoc to me.

Comment: Tested this implementation and it isn't doing what it is supposed to. Relying on 'graph' comparison using the laplacian spectrum makes it focus too much on the number of in/out arcs, and so the 'attributes' of each particular node are practically ignored. I tried adding weights for both nodes and edges and it doesn't fix this fundamental problem. Does anyone have a better way to compare subgraphs? Edit-distance seems promising but have yet to find a Python implementation....